# fb.api returns 'undefined' on connected user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Below code gives me an 'undefined' on the name and email. However the user IS logged in because I DO have the access token and UID?

```
function getToken(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            document.getElementById('accessToken').value=access_token;
            document.getElementById('uid').value=uid;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' +response.email);
            });
            document.forms['token'].submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, {scope:'email,user_likes,friends_likes'});
}
```

When I output the complete response of fb.api to console I get

```
[11:46:10.369] ({error:"load-error: unknown"})
```

Comment: Can you try to just log the entire response and post it here so that we'll know what facebook respond with? Something like: *console.log(response);*

Comment: --
[11:46:10.369] ({error:"load-error: unknown"})

Comment: First time I see this type of error. Can you maybe try a simpler flow? just call for login, then in the callback just check for the *authResponse* and if it exists call the *FB.api* with */me* and then just log the response. Remove the other code, especially the form submitting. Then please post here the responses you get from fb for the login and */me* requests.

Comment: Everything else in this script is working. I DO get the access token and DO get the userID

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but still, when things do go according to plan, it's usually best to simplify things in order to see what goes wrong and where. Just give it a go and we'll see what's the result.

Comment: The line causing the issue is found

     document.forms['token'].submit();

Comment: Ha, I had a feeling, which is why I told you to try a simplified version.

Comment: This still doesn't solve it...

Comment: The same exact error? Can you please update your question (edit it) with the new simplified code?

Comment: It's very simple, if I remove the submit, the response is ok. But what is the use if I cannot submit the form? So the REAL question is why a perfectly good javascript line is breaking the fb.api

Comment: I don't know what it is you're trying to do... You did not show the code for the form in question, what's the point of submitting it anyhow? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to have the access_token and user ID somewhere else in PHP, so I submit a form. Nothing fancy. What the rest of code look like doesn't matter. The real question is why fb.api breaks on a perfectly good javascript line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now see what you are trying to do and the problem.

Why it fails:

You are making an asynchronous request (using the *FB.api* method) and then submit a form (and it's a guess since you did not include all code) which reloads the entire page, messing up with the async request.

As for how to solve the problem:

The best solution, in my opinion, is to use the [Server-Side authentication process](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and only then, afterwards, when the canvas loads use the client side sdk.
That way you'll have access tokens both in the client and server side.

Another approach is not to submit the form, but to issue a ajax request to your server (it can be in POST) with the access token, since both the requests will be asynchronous (*FB.api* and the one to your server) everything should be a ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick fix would be submitting the form inside the FB.api function.
So it would look like:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' +response.email);
            document.forms['token'].submit();
});
```